# IONIC2 Calendar : Want to offset the next available row to top after hiding all the Hours row

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I just implemented a WEEK calendar as mentioned in the reference https://devdactic.com/ionic-calendar-app/

I can see the week calendar and manage to hide "all-day" row and all the "hour" rows from it using the below css.

```
  .weekview-allday-table {
        display:none;
      }

      .weekview-normal-event-container{
        display:none;
      }

      .calendar-event-wrap{
        display:none;
      }

      .weekview-normal-event-container {
      margin-top: 0;
      }
```

Please find the below snapshot.

[image]
[image]
I need to move the below activity list next to the calendar header. Could you suggest how that can be done.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in `scss` file

```
.weekview-container{
    height: 12% !important;
  }
```

override the `css`.